# Roulette selection function for a genetic algorithm

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, roulette-wheel-selection

So I've written a roulette selection function for my genetic algorithm which follows:

```
public String tournament(float fitness, Chromosome pop[], int selection)
{
    // roulette
    if (selection == 1)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        float slice = random.nextFloat() * fitness;

        float curFitness = 0.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < initialPopulation; i++)
        {
            curFitness += pop[i].fitness;

            if (curFitness >= slice)
                return pop[i].bits;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The problem is that it is sometimes returning the blank string, which has only been placed their to satisfy the return condition. This is generally not a problem, but during some runs it causes the GA to terminate since the next step involves the crossover stage. Any ideas?

Comment: under what condition will you fail to return from the statement in the loop?  Why is that happening?  Put in some debug lines and find out. Or run it with the debugger.

Comment: This code will fail in the case of a minimization problem.

Comment: I realize that I am a bit late to this party, but user the 'fitness' value that you are passing into this function, is it the sum of all the individual fitnesses?  Just curious as to how this works.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out the mutation function was occasionally nulling some of my bit strings, which was causing the population to contain empty strings.

Before, it looked like this:

```
public String mutate(String bits)
{   
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(bits);
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++)
    {
        if (random.nextFloat() < mutationRate)
        {
            if (bits.charAt(i) == '1')
            {
                buf.setCharAt(i, '0');
                                    return buf.toString();

            }
            else
            {
                buf.setCharAt(i, '1');
                                    return buf.toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And I changed it to this:

```
public String mutate(String bits)
{   
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(bits);
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++)
    {
        if (random.nextFloat() < mutationRate)
        {
            if (bits.charAt(i) == '1')
            {
                buf.setCharAt(i, '0');
            }
            else
            {
                buf.setCharAt(i, '1');
            }
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the problem is that your `fitness` is occasionally less than the sum of your `pop[i].fitness`es.  Try putting a `return "ERROR: " + fitness + " / " + curFitness;` line after the `for` loop but within the `if`, or something of that nature, and see what gets returned.